# Replicate CSS Animation on ::after using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've done a lot of searching, and can't seem to find another question that helps. However I feel like this might be a common problem so could be a duplicate, anyway.

I have a really nice CSS Underline animation going on when I hover a piece of text, you can see the example here:

```js
let options = ['Over Here', 'This Way', 'At Me']

$(document).ready(function () {
  let jobInterval = setInterval(() => changeText(), 3000)
})

function changeText () {
  let newText = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]
  $('#change').text(newText)
}
```

```css
#change {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
#change:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
}
#change:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>
    <span>Look </span>
    <span id="change">Over Here</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6b2cqrj7/7/

However, I don't want it to be done when I hover. The idea is that I have a piece of text that changes every X seconds, and I want the underline to animate for X seconds then the word switches and the animation plays again. Like a little timer bar.

I have tried all sorts, but because I can't manipulate the ::after tag using JS/JQuery I can't work out how to get this working.
Because the animation is happening on the ::after tag, I can't just add a new class I need to change the value of the CSS so the transition will apply. I think.

This is my first real attempt at using CSS animations so I'm quite stumped here.

Comment: try using `keyframes` in your `:after` element or animate it using `setInterval` in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS3 `keyframes` to get the desired result.

```js
let options = ['Over Here', 'This Way', 'At Me']

$(document).ready(function () {
  let jobInterval = setInterval(() => changeText(), 3000)
})

function changeText () {
  let newText = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]
  $('#change').text(newText)
}
```

```css
#change {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
#change:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    animation: myLine 3s ease infinite;
    transition: width 3s ease, background-color 3s ease;
}
#change:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

@keyframes myLine{
  from {width: 0; background: transparent;}
  to {width: 100%; background: red;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>
    <span>Look </span>
    <span id="change">Over Here</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I could kiss you! Thank you so much... now I gotta go and research keyframes though

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers.